# R, right xpath to grab the text using xpathSApply

Tags: r, xpath

It's a simple xpath exercise, but I cannot get it work.

When I inspect the element of a button (using google chrom), it gives this tree -
I'd like to grab the title, such as "Distinguished Contributor" or "Board Manager".

```
<span class="author-by"></span>

<span class="UserName lia-user-name">

    <img id="display_3" class="lia-user-rank-icon-left" alt="Distinguished Contributor" title="Distinguished Contributor"></img>

.....

<span class="author-by"></span>

<span class="UserName lia-user-name">

    <img id="display_25" class="lia-user-rank-icon-left" alt="Board Manager" title="Board Manager"></img>
```

So far, I tried

```
> xpathSApply(htmltree, "//img[@class='lia-user-rank-icon-left']", xmlGetAttr, "href")

> test = "//img/@title"
> a <- xpathSApply(htmltree, test, function(x) c(xmlValue(x), xmlAttrs(x)[["href"]]))
```

and a bunch of others, but it wasn't successful yet. Any guidance will be very appreciated!

Comment: You can right click on the thing you want when you are the looking at the source of the page and then select _Copy XPath_, and that should help. What is the actual page?

Comment: should "href" be "title"?

Comment: Yeah, I think @RandyLai is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a example for getting the source of images with class 'dno'. I think in your case, you have to change 'dno' and 'src'.

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
text = getURL("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024062/r-right-xpath-to-grab-the-text-using-xpathsapply")
d = htmlParse(text)
L = xpathApply(d, "//img[@class='dno']")
sapply(L, xmlGetAttr, "src")
```

You can replace the last two lines by `xpathApply(d, "//img[@class='dno']", xmlGetAttr, "src")`. However, for debugging purposes, it is better to split it into two commands.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it's better to split it into two commands. :)